# Find $XY$ given matrix $YX$ where $X$ is a row matrix and $Y$ is a column matrix

Tags: matrices

I've been given matrix $YX$ as below. I want to find $XY$ from it. I know that $X$ is a row matrix and $Y$ is a column matrix. $X$ has $2$ entries and $Y$ has $2$ entries. However I don't know the values of each entry.

$$YX=
\begin{bmatrix}
-2 & -3 \\ 
2 & 3
\end{bmatrix}$$

I'm not quite sure how to progress from here. I know that the result will be one number. I'd like some guidance on where to go next.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: $$\begin{bmatrix}a \\ b\end{bmatrix}\times\begin{bmatrix}c & d\end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix}ac & ad \\ bc & bd\end{bmatrix}$$

Then:
$$\begin{bmatrix}c & d\end{bmatrix}\times\begin{bmatrix}a \\ b\end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix}ac +bd\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: Oh I see now. Thank you for explaining this to me. From the above I believe that $XY = 1$

Comment: @Pije, $XY = [(-2)+(3)] = [1]$.  The answer is a $1\times 1$ matrix and not a scalar value.

Answer (score 1):

If $Y=\begin{bmatrix}a\\b\end{bmatrix}$ and $X=\begin{bmatrix}c&d\end{bmatrix}$, we know that $ac=-2$ and $bc=2$, i.e., $b=-a$. Likewise we find $d=\frac32 c$. So $Y=u\cdot \begin{bmatrix}1\\-1\end{bmatrix}$ and $X=v\cdot \begin{bmatrix}1&\frac32\end{bmatrix}$. Moreover, $uv=-2$ and we finde $XY=uv(1+\frac32)=1$.

Answer (score 0):

$YX = \pmatrix{-1\\1}\pmatrix{2&3}=\pmatrix{-2&-3\\2&3}$ therefore $XY = \pmatrix{2&3} \pmatrix{-1\\1}=1.$